# How to Create Admin grid value type of multiselect and Drop down?

Tags: magento-1.9, grid

i am creating admin side grid. in that grid few value i am getting from table. but few value need to select by Admin.
    as seen below figure.
[image]

here, column **Time sheet** value type will be MultiSelect,so that Admin can Select any one or more.

if **select one** value then beside it in column of  MEAL it will create **one dropdown**. with two value 1) Before 2) After.

if **select two** value then beside it in column of  MEAL it will create **two dropdown**. with two value 1) Before 2) After.

how to create it friend?

Please if you know help me.

Edit: I do not want in Filter. i want it in value row.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a 'renderer' to generate your column data.  This allows you to render out HTML (or anything else) as you column data so you can build things like dropdowns and multiselects.  If you use that and want to search by that column, you will probably also want to look at the 'filter_condition_callback'.  This allows you to call a custom method when searching by a column.

[This](http://www.atwix.com/magento/grid-filter-for-columns/) seems to be a reasonable, quick summary of the subject.